# Pyside removes newline on resize, ignores text wrapping policy

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a problem with Python 3.3 and pyside 1.2.1. I want to create a QTableView with (for example) 10 rows and 10 columns, without word- or linewrapping. 
However, when I try to resize the first column, it just removes the linebreak, which is undesirable. So if my first entry looked like:

---

column 0

row 0

---

It would now look like:

---

column 0 row 0

---

Is there any way I can disable this behaviour? I searched through the qt-source but couldn't find why it does this.

Thanks in advance

```
import sys
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTableView
from PySide.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, Qt

class TableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return 10
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return 10
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return "column %d\nrow %d" % (index.column(), index.row())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow(None)
    table = QTableView(window)
    table.setWordWrap(False)
    window.setCentralWidget(table)
    table.setModel(TableModel())
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: I've found a relevant bug report for this issue: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3248

It has been inactive for a while, so I don't see this being fixed soon :/ One possible solution is using two new line characters. I found that is accomodates the bug pretty well.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works around the problem very nice. Funny how I didn't think of that...